# What is the meaning of range and len in my code?

Tags: python, machine-learning

In part of my code i have this:

```
plt.plot(range(1, len(ppn.errors_) +1), ppn.errors_, marker = 'o')
```

Where ppn.errors_ is a vector. What's is the meaning of all this line? (considering numbers 1?

```
ppn = Perceptron(eta = 0.1, n_iter = 10)
ppn.fit(X, y) 
plt.plot(range(1, len(ppn.errors_) +1), ppn.errors_, marker = 'o')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.ylabel('Number of updates')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You are asking for someone to explain your own code to you?

Comment: What does the documentation tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`len()` gives you the size of the iterable, so in this case `len(ppn.errors_)` is the size of the vector (number of elements/dimensions).

`range(a,b)` will give you a range of numbers from a (inclusive) to b (exclusive).

So `range(1, len(ppn.errors_) +1)` is a range of values starting at 1 and ending at the length/size of the vector `ppn.errors_`.

Say `ppn.errors_  = [7,8,9,10]`, then:

`len(ppn.errors_) = 4`

`range(1, len(ppn.errors_) +1) = range(1, 4+1) = range(1,5)`

where `range(1,5)` is the range `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

`range(1, len(ppn.errors_) +1)` is a contiguous range of integers `1, 2, ..., n` where n is the length of `ppn.errors_`.

`plt.plot`'s first two argument are the `x` coordinates and `y` coordinates respectively. Since you likely have a series that you just want to plot in order it makes sense to use `1, 2, ...` as your x coordinates of your plot.

Answer (score 0):

`range(a, b)` will produce an iterator starting from `a` up to `b - 1`.
If the starting index 'a' is not specified, it defaults to '0'

An `iterator` is simply something onto which you can apply `for` loop (Example `list`, `tuple`)

`len(a)` returns the number of element in `a`

Example:

```
range(5) # returns an iterator containing 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

So, `list(range(5))` will return `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`, because `list()` function converts the given `iterator` to a `list`

```
a = list(range(2, 7)) # [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
x = len(a)
print(x) # Prints 5
```

Hope it helped. Tell me if there is something you didn't understand